# Deterministic Function is Non-Deterministic

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 10.50.1600

I am trying to use a scalar valued function in a computed column. I then wish to create an index off of this.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Modified]
ADD [StartQDate] AS ([dbo].[QDay]([StartDT])) PERSISTED,
    [EndQDate]   AS ([dbo].[QDay]([EndDT])) PERSISTED;
```

I am receiving the following error when I try to create the computed column.

> Computed column 'StartQDate' in table 'Modified' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Except for the fact that my scalar function QDay is defined as

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[QDay] 
(
@Date DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN YEAR(@Date)*10000+MONTH(@Date)*100+DAY(@Date)
END
```

Which according to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) should be deterministic.

Even if I change the function to

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[QDay] 
(
@Date DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END
```

I still get the Non-Deterministic error message.

I have this working on another server. I'm at a loss on what to do.

Comment: Why use a scalar function at all? `EndQDate As Year(EndDT)*10000+Month(EndDT)*100+DAY(EndDT)`?

Comment: Maybe `DATETIME` is not deterministic? The page you linked indicates that other functions are deterministic unless used with `DATETIME`, and `DATETIME` is not listed in the guaranteed deterministic functions.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037330/why-is-date-time-offset-non-deterministic-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to add

```
WITH SCHEMABINDING
```

as suggested in this question [Sql Server deterministic user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651662/sql-server-deterministic-user-defined-function)

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[QDay] 
(
    @Date DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN YEAR(@Date)*10000+MONTH(@Date)*100+DAY(@Date)
END
```